# Firebase JSON Tree Structure

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, data-structures, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a project involving students at schools. As I have started to build this project I have encountered three major questions:

1) Which JSON tree structure is recommended or better?

```
schools

  grades

    users(uids)

      info
```

or

```
users(uids)

  info (includes school and grade)
```

2) If I were to use the first structure, how would I access the user's grade and school, which is vital to be able to access the rest of the user's contact information, upon first logging in?

3) If I were to use the second structure, wouldn't it be too many users to query through to find all the people in one grade of one of many schools?

Somebody please help. At this point, I'm just super confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make separate nodes for user's info, and the other node for member of grade of school

```
schooldb

   schools

      grades

         users(uids)
```

and for getting info

```
userdb

 users(uids)

    info (includes school and grade)
```

This is a necessary redundancy for two-way relationships

Answer (score 2):

Before getting Into it mark some points which are best practices for firebase :-

Avoid nesting data

Flatten data structures

Create data that scales

Turn on the persistace storage so that you can query data from local storage which will be fast enough to make user experiance better

for more info - [check this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data)

Answer (score 1):

I feel below JSON structure will be nice. I'm not sure of it as I don't know exact requirement of yours. It depends on your requirement. But always the recommended way is to try to create more independent nodes as you can access data through queries.

```
schools

   users(uids)

      Grades or info based on relation between grades and users
```